# Can I list all available index servers with pip?

Tags: pip

I have added an index server in my `~/.pypirc` file as:

```
[distutils]
index-servers = example

[example]
repository: https://example.com/simple/
username: someplaintextusername
password: someplaintextpw
```

However, I can't install a package which definitely is on the `example` index server. Now I want to check if pip actually notices that server in the `pypirc` file.

Can I make `pip` list all available index servers?

edit: For the problem I'm trying to solve, it seems as if `~/config/pip/pip.config` is the file I should edit. But my question is still the same.

Comment: @sinoroc Cool, that is 90% of what I wanted! If you would make that an answer, I would at least upvote it :-)

Comment: One thing I'm missing is some indicator if pip can use it. For example, it could be that pip can't find any package on that server (e.g. connectivity issue or missing credentials). Is it possible to list how many packages are on each of the index servers?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 4):

*pip*'s own [`config list`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_config/) command should get you at least some of this info:

```
path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip config list
```